# Should I use an Observable or a BindingList for exposing changing data that I want to put into a UI

Tags: c#, signalr, system.reactive, bindinglist

I'm trying to get myself into using Rx (Xamarin Forms) in a ViewModel first approach. What I'm slightly unsure about is the best way of exposing changing information that my data model needs to provide to the view models.

I have a service that provides my client a snapshot of data and then provides updated events via signalr that indicate add, update and remove. I've written an application wrapper for my client data model that logs in, manages state and general connectivity and has a local database (SqlLite in my case).

What I would like is to expose the data on my application wrapper with changing events so that I can then bind to the events and create an observable collection that I can then use in WPF/Xamarin.

I can use Rx for this or more traditional approaches such as BindingList. I'm finding it hard to decide what I should do. My use case is this:

1. I want to get a full list of all of my local items after login
2. I want to be notified of changes (adds, updates and removes) and react
3. I want to convert the above into view models and an observable collection as appropriate.

I would want to be able to subscribe to a given collection and get all of the entries currently local to me, but to also monitor changes that could happen via SignalR. Should this be Rx? Or should I hide Rx behind a BindingList (for example).

So is it:

```
IObservable<MyOrder> Orders { get; } // What kind of subject?
```

Or

```
BindingList<MyOrder> Orders { get; }
```

Or something else?

And if its the Rx one, what should I do to make sure that each subscriber gets the current orders list and then gets changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the ViewModel you want to expose your data as state. So ViewModels that implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` or expose readonly properties that themselves expose INPC (INotifyPropertyChanged) is good. In this case the VM (ViewModel) would have an `Orders` property

```
BindingList<MyOrder> Orders { get; }
```

Then the VM I would think would subscribe to an Observable Sequence of change notifications. This sounds like your SignalR channel provides you this already. In previous projects we conflated Add/Insert and Update into a single "upsert" message, and then had Remove/Delete and Clear/Reset messages too.

The difficulty you will get by trying to manage state locally is the "State of the World" problem. If you try to get the current snapshot first, then subscribe to live values, you can miss a value while reading the snapshot. If however, you subscribe first then get the snapshot, you may receive a value twice. In this case you will also have to deal with queuing the live data until you have processed the snapshot.

With this in mind, you can either try to move everything to a single threaded and predictable sequence model, or just get something else that does this for you (Akavache?). If you do think it is worth doing yourself, then it is probably worth trying a model that uses checkpoints/sequenceIds, so the client can just resubscribe from a known point. This will allow the service to either give them just the recent changes, or a full snapshot if their checkpoint is suffciently stale.

So, yeah expose it as an

```
IObservable<ChangeNotification<MyOrder>> OrderChanges { get;}
```

Where `ChangeNotification` conveys either an Upsert (with new items), Deletion (with ids/keys to delete) or Reset.
You wont use a subject anywhere if it is done properly ;-)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to understand the problem and giving me a decent response. I was kinda guessing at the ChangeNotification observable myself. I would probably favour exposing an ObservableCollection at the VM level. Out of interest what is the thing about not using Subjects in Rx? They seem quite taboo for some reason.

Comment: There is a good chance that I started the taboo. But as Erik (the inventor) also suggest to avoid them, I don't think I am the crazy person. As a general coding rule, I dont think you have to justify *not* using a tool, but instead the burden should be on you to give justify the cost of using the tool. In a recent post (https://leecampbell.com/2016/10/03/iprogress-and-rx-without-subjects/) I declare Subjects are to Rx what `GOTO` is to C#. The sample shows one example of not using them and reducing the code significantly too.

Comment: If you want to see how Reactive GUIs can be built and other concerns that you probably should consider beyond caching like connectivity, security, configuration, load etc. check out the presentations from ReactConf or YOW https://leecampbell.com/presentations/